# passing parameters among files

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ipad

consider 4 files:Login.h, Login.m, Handler.h, Handler.m

```
Login.h
@class Handler 
  NSString *allResponse;
- (void)handleAllResponse:(NSString*m)response passSelf:(NikeLogin*)LoginSelf;

Login.m
#import Handler.h
[self handleAllResponse:response passSelf:self];

Handler.h
#import Login.h
NSString *allResponse;

Handler.m
- (void)handleAllResponse:(NSString*)response passSelf:(NikeLogin*)LoginSelf
{
allResponse=[LoginSelf parseCommunities:response];
//variables assigned values
}
-(NSString*)parseCommunities:(NSString*)response 
{
 //code  
}
```

the compiler is not recognizing handleAllCommunitiesResponse method definition in Handler.h and hence not calling it from Login.m.
Also The variables in handleAllCommunitiesResponse method have to be redeclared in Handler.h
The main aim of this is to declare methods in Login.h and define them in Handler.m for modularization and in some cases as above the method is called from Login.m
In the above code self is passed from Login.m so that all methods and variables are accessible in Handler.m, but it is not happening.

Please help!!

Comment: What is the 'naked' method call in Login.m? What is self supposed to mean in that context (outside any method definition)? Is Login a class too? If not, what is the purpose of the module?

Answer (score 1):

Are you quoting your `#import`s?  Those should be:

`#import "Login.h"`

Comment: The first one is Login.m file, it does not contain any import but a forward class declaration of @class Handler

Comment: That didn't answer my question.  Furthermore, if you're only using forward declarations instead of imports, then no, the compiler won't have any idea about those method signatures.  You seem to have posted pretty incomplete code--please post something that actually shows what you're doing and is failing.